# If and else if in PHP, colon style

Tags: php

One function of PHP that I like to use is the colon-style if statement (I don't know what it's actually called.)

```
<?php if(something):?>
    <html stuff>
<?php endif;?>
```

But I recently tried to do this with multiple cases:

```
<?php if(something):?>
    <html stuff>
<?php else if(something):?>
    <html stuff>
<?php endif;?>
```

And I get an error on the third line (the `else if`):

> Unexpected T_IF

Is it possible to make an if-else if this way?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I don't think it is worth to post the question and especially not if you have already solved the problem (You answered your own question immediately). It's simply a syntax error which is considered `off-topic`

Comment: @hek2mgl It was not a typographical error though. I actually solved my problem as I was writing the question, but I thought the community could benefit from the knowledge presented in this question. else if (2 words) is completely valid in PHP; it is not a typographical error.

Comment: @MathNerdProductions 1. `Parse error:` **syntax error,** `unexpected 'if' (T_IF)` it is a syntax error. 2. Everyone who reads the manual knows this

Comment: @Rizier123 You misunderstand me. I am saying that what he was saying, that it is a typographical error, is not true. `else if` is a valid synonym in PHP, but not in this specific case. I have found no questions on S.O. that explains this, so I thought that posting a Q&A to this question would benefit the community.

Comment: @Rizier123 I think this is to harsh.. If you would have asked me that at "Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?" I would have used the phone joker.. :) Normally `else if` (with a space in between) is pretty ok in PHP. But yes, it is still a syntax error.

Comment: @hek2mgl: [Posting a question you already know the answer to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/) has been an encouraged activity since SO was in beta. There's a [dedicated button for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/). Whether the question is a good and useful one is a separate issue, but sharing a solution to a problem that others might have is _completely_ acceptable, no matter who formulated the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to get it to work.

In this very specific case, `else if` is not synonymous with `elseif`.

Substituting `elseif` for `else if` fixes the issue.

```
<?php if(something):?>
    <html stuff>
<?php elseif(something):?>
    <html stuff>
<?php endif;?>
```

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php):

> Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.

Comment: It might be worth including the explanation from [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php#115851) about *why* it doesn't work. Namely that `else if` is actually a single-statement `else` whose statement happens to be an `if`, and the colon is not optional in the alternative syntax, unlike the {} in the normal syntax.