# Show content based on Category count in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I would like to display my content based on a category count being > 0.

I have found this php snippet:
`<?php if (get_category('17')->category_count > 0); ?>`

And only want to show the below content in my template if the above category is 1 or more.

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/professional-chef/products/accompaniments/">
        <?php 
            if( get_field('accompaniments_range_image', 'option') ) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_field('accompaniments_range_image', 'option'), 'full' );
            }else{
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/placeholder-range.jpg" alt="Range Placeholder Image" width="528" height="718">';
            }
        ?>
        <span>Accompaniments</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I've tried the following with no luck, where am I going wrong?

```
<?php if (get_category('17')->category_count > 0) echo '
<div class="entry-content">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/professional-chef/products/accompaniments/">
        <?php 
            if( get_field('accompaniments_range_image', 'option') ) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_field('accompaniments_range_image', 'option'), 'full' );
            }else{
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/placeholder-range.jpg" alt="Range Placeholder Image" width="528" height="718">';
            }
        ?>
        <span>Accompaniments</span>
    </a>
</div>'
; ?>
```

Comment: use the alternate if version, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592979/if-and-else-if-in-php-colon-style so that you can wrap up markup inside

Comment: Difficult to try it, but it looks like there is a block of code under the `if` statement, so rather than just the `echo`, open a code block with a `{` - `category_count > 0) { ?>' and close it at the end - so change `; ?>` to `<?php } ?>`.  See if it works.

Comment: `if (get_category('17',ARRAY_A)->category_count > 0)` Give it a try.

Comment: @Kevin I just checked my URL of my product categories and I think I may be using `get_category` incorrectly. Here is a snippet of my URL:
`com.au/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=product_taxonomy&tag_ID=19&post_type=products&`
I am trying to target the count in the product_taxonomy which I thought were categories...